# Check if exists and replace

Tags: php, fonts, colors, tags

```
$server['s']['name'] = "§4Hello world i'm §1Mafios_X";
//

$name = $server['s']['name'];
```

How I can check if the `$name` exist `$4` change it in `<font color="red">` and close the `</font>` tag before another `$4` (or some `$`), if doesn't exist any other `$`, close after `$name` finish.

How I can make this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you meant `§` instead of `$` you can check it with preg_match() if you want to replace it you can use str_replace or preg_replace

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well

```
if(preg_match('/(§4)/', $name)) // if '§4' exists in $name it will go into conditional block
{
   $name = preg_replace('/(§4)/', '/<font color="red">$1<\/font>/', $str); // we replace it 
}
else
{
  //it doesn't exists
   $name.="</font>"; // we close with font tag
}
```

Basicly it's all about `preg_replace('/(§4)/', '/<font color="red">$1<\/font>/', $str);` which will change every `§4` for `<font color="red">§4<\/font>`